# ASP.NET MVC Navbar with glyphicons and text

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Hi StackOverFlow people.

Im a bit new to the whole asp.net MVC and im trying to make my own homepage but im struggling with the navbar + glyphicons. I dont have enough reputation to show pictures so ill drop a link to the pictures instead.

What Im trying to make a navbar with icons + text where the Icon should be above the text. What im aiming for is looking like this:
[image: What im trying to do]

But this is what I get:
[image]

Here is my code And thanks

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#home"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a></li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                <li><a href="#contact"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope">Contact</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#shop"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart">Shop</span></a></li>
            </ul>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
    </footer>
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your links don't work

Comment: Im sorry.. I'll fix that.

Comment: I'm now able to show images.. I've updated it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to display in the next line:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
               Home
                </a>
           </li>
          <li>
                <a href="@Url.Action("About", "Home")">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
                Index
                </a>
           </li>
          </ul>
</div>
```

If you want to Display Icon in line:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li  class="text-center">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span><br/>
                Home
                </a>
           </li>
          <li class="text-center">
                <a href="@Url.Action("About", "Home")">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span><br/>
                About
                </a>
           </li>
          </ul>
</div>
```

Fiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdawood1991/pnb7g99s/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have markup issue. Try this:

```
<li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span><br /><a href="#contact">Contact</span></li>
<li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span><br /><a href="#shop"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart">Shop</a></li>
```

Or you can try to put spans inside of anchor tag. Play around with that a little bit. And if you won't succeed, create jsfiddle or plunker. And explain how do you see it.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
 <a href="#home">
 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
 <span> Home</span>
```